# MS SQL Server Convert Date

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have a `Date` column, within it, dates are in two formats, see below.

```
Date
------------------------
2/28/2017 10:00
2017-03-15 10:00:00
```

I want to convert the dates that are `mm/dd/yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-yy` within the `date` column, however, my script is not converting rows that are `mm/dd/yyyy`.

I am not sure what I else I might be missing or doing wrong.

My script

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DateColumn, 120) AS [Receipt Date] 
FROM 
    databasename.dbo.sales
```

Answer (score 0):

Review your SQL Statement  NVARCHAR needs a declaration on lenght: NVarchar(10)

```
declare @mydate datetime

set @mydate = GETDATE();

select CONVERT(nvarchar(10),@mydate,120)
```

Comment: do I change @mydate to the column of the source table

Comment: iDebug, SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,datecolumn) from sourcetable works

Comment: that means that your field is not a datetime field, it is a string based field

Answer (score 0):

```
Use 
SET DateFormat dmy
Or
SET LANGUAGE French; 
Then
declare @mydate datetime
set @mydate = GETDATE();
select CONVERT(nvarchar(10),@mydate,12
```

0)